# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I keep getting this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

This is the query:

```
$query = $connection->prepare("INSERT into payments ([order],email,method,transaction) VALUES (:order,:email,:method,:transaction)");
$query->bindValue(":order",$orderid);
$query->bindValue(":email",$payeremail);
$query->bindValue(":method",$paypal);
$query->bindValue(":transaction",$transaction_id);
$query->execute();
```

The reason I have added [] around 'order' is because it is a reserved word? I get this error with and without these brackets...

Can anyone help me on this?

I have never experienced this error before...

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you roll back my update? I removed the spaces which were not needed.

Comment: Sorry , i think i was editing and you updated at the same time. I will try your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reserved word you need to use back ticks (``) not square brackets.

Change,

```
$query = $connection->prepare("INSERT into payments ([order],email,method,transaction) VALUES (:order,:email,:method,:transaction)");
```

To,

```
 $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT into payments (`order`,email,method,transaction) VALUES (:order,:email,:method,:transaction)");
```

Comment: @user3882630 glad I could help.